Azure App Service Not Updating .NET Core 8.0 Application Despite Version Change
I'm using Visual Studio 2022 publish profiles to deploy a Blazor .NET Core 8.0 application to an Azure Linux App Service. We're trying to update the version number, but the changes aren't being reflected in the deployed application. Here's what we've done:
Updated the project file with the following properties:
<PropertyGroup>
    <VersionPrefix>2.1.0</VersionPrefix>
    <VersionInfo>$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString(yyyyMMddHHmmss))</VersionInfo>
    <InformationalVersion>$(VersionPrefix)-$(VersionInfo)</InformationalVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

Confirmed that a local build of the file shows updated version and informational values in the binary.
Enabled the "Remove Additional files at destination" option in the publish profile, which should delete the old content before each publish.
However, when we deploy to Azure:
The changes are not detected.
The binary on the server remains the same.
The publish process indicates success, but the old site is still present.
What we've tried:
Verifying local build reflects the version changes.

Enabling "Remove Additional files at destination" in the publish profile.

Questions:
Has anyone else observed this behavior with Azure App Service deployments?
Are there any other options available to ensure the new version is deployed correctly?
Could there be any caching issues on Azure's end preventing the update?

After testing, it not happens in my side, but I still to search it. And found a useful blog.

So I have some suggestions below.

Check the tier you are using. In my side, I am using S1.

Try to restart the application in azure portal.


Set WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE = 0.


